# Getting a countertop dishwasher to work in a convenient manner

Tags: kitchens, faucet, dishwasher

I purchased a Koldfront countertop dishwasher for an old home I've just bought.

I'm up to my knees in expenses and projects, so I don't want to get into anything major, like having a plumber trying to run a new hose to it (or trying to do that myself yet).

However, I want to get it working -- currently the faucet connection doesn't seem to fit the only faucet in the kitchen sink -- **and** I want to make it such that I don't have to unscrew my Brita water filter and screw on the dishwasher adapter every time I use it.

To get it working I think I need to order a "faucet adapter" from Sears for about $20 (?).

My real question is on the 2nd part -- what would I have to do to make it where I can permanently (or semi-permanently) attach both the Brita water filter and the dishwasher to the same kitchen sink faucet?

Is there some sort of diverter I could use to do this?

Comment: When I was a kid we had a dishwasher that had a [quick disconnect](http://www.ebay.com/itm/Faucet-QuickSnap-Adapter-for-Whirlpool-Kenmore-Maytag-Portable-DishWasher-Washer-/301769847136) to the faucet. I saw several other types that did not look as nice but had both male and female. if you have 2 it would only take a second to swap the dishwasher and water filter.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issu than you. I'm expecting to put a [divider](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07TFCCQ1C) and to connect the brita on one end and the dishwasher quick connect on the other end. I could also use an [elbow adaptor](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0824674BG) if I wish both faucet to face down. By now, it's the better option I found. I also try to find another quick connect to connect to the brita and switch on the brita and the dishwasher when I need it (as suggest by the other comment) but I didn't find any wet.